# Vertx configuring logging with Log4j

Tags: java, log4j, vert.x

My gradle dependencies:

```
compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.1"
compile "io.vertx:vertx-core:3.4.2"
compile 'io.vertx:vertx-web:3.4.2'
```

My log4 config is in `src/main/resouces/log4.xml`
Config's contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Before creating Vertx instance I have this line:

```
System.setProperty(
    "vertx.logger-delegate-factory-class-name", 
    "io.vertx.core.logging.SLF4JLogDelegateFactory"
)
```

But when request is made, nothing is logged. How can I configure it correctly?

Comment: Either you have a system property defined as `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=src/main/resouces/log4.xml`(make sure it is full path) or rename the file to `log4j2.xml`. Please [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) for more information.

Comment: I assume this is just a typo, but path contains `/resouces/` instead of `/resources`, maybe this is causing you problems if the folder has the wrong name?

Answer (score 2):

You want to log with `log4j` but you set the factory class name to `slf4j`.

The right property value is `io.vertx.core.logging.Log4jLogDelegateFactory`

See the [logging](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_using_another_logging_framework) section in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

> You can also configure log  using `log4j.properties` defined in  `src/main/resouces/` folder

```
    # Root logger option
    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

    # Redirect log messages to console
    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

    log4j.logger.io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx= ERROR

    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.File=./logs/auth.log  

     log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy       
     log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy.ActiveFileName =./logs/auth.log   


     log4j.appender.file.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=./logs/logs.%d{yyyyMMdd}.gz
     log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
     log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

> I hope this will help you :)